# Filter Students by their highest marks

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table

table name 'results'

```
Reg.No  SubjectCode  Attempt  Grade  Marks
112108  CMIS 1113    1        D      17
112110  CMIS 1114    1        A      85
112119  CMIS 1114    1        D      18
112108  CMIS 1113    2        D+     25
112110  CMIS 1113    1        D+     25
112107  CMIS 1113    1        B      70
112108  CMIS 1113    3        C      40
112110  CMIS 1113    2        C      40
112119  CMIS 1114    2        C      42
112120  CMIS 1114    1        D      17
```

This is about students' results.
 Students need at least a "C"
    (marks>40) to pass the subject.
 Until pass, students can have
    several attempts.
 But from the second attempt maximum grade they
    can get is "C"
 So students who was unable to pass the subject in
    first attempt,used to have another try until they pass the subjects
    
So for final results sheet the highest result will be take into account in each subjects.(highest results is given by the highest marks)
So for example highest marks of 112108 for CMIS 1113 is 40.
So likewise I want to get the students results for ecch subjects(But always maximum marks will be take into account)
Actually my expected results table should be like this

```
Reg.No  SubjectCode  Attempt  Grade  Marks
112110  CMIS 1114    1        A      85
112107  CMIS 1113    1        B      70
112108  CMIS 1113    3        C      40
112110  CMIS 1113    2        C      40
112119  CMIS 1114    2        C      42
112120  CMIS 1114    1        D      17
```

So how can I retrieve these data using sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only one value per student, you group by Reg.No and SubjectCode and then get the max value for each subject. This query should work:

```
SELECT      
    `Reg.No`,
    `SubjectCode`,
    `Attempt`,
    `Grade`,
    MAX(`marks`) AS marks
FROM        
    `results` 
GROUP BY    
    `Reg.No`, `SubjectCode`
```

In order to get all columns, you need two queries, which can be put together with a subquery. It will look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM `results` 
     ORDER BY `Grade` ASC) AS t
GROUP BY    
    `Reg.No`, `SubjectCode` 
ORDER BY    
    `Grade` ASC
```

The "inner query" will get all results and order the rows by the `Grade` column from low to high. The "outer query" will than just group them (without the usage of the `MAX` function). This will result in only the last row for each grouping, which is than the max result (as we ordered it that way in the "inner query").

Comment: Thank you sir.This  works fine.But I want to get the grade as well.When I select grade column, then it will not give the expected results.It shows max(marks) but grade is not belongs to the max(marks).With out grade column your query work fine.But if I get grade column,expected results won't come

Comment: That's correct. If you want all additional colums for that max value, you need a more complex query. Give me a minute or two to extend my answer.

Comment: Always a pleasure to help. And I really like such query questions. BTW: Feel free to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: I like your explanations.It helps me to learn new things.Thank you sir for your kindness

Comment: I am glad it helped you. I always try not to give only a correct solution but also explain, why and how it solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to establish which is the highest mark and join to that:

```
SELECT r.`Reg.No`, r.SubjectCode, MAX(Attempt), r.Grade, r.marks
FROM results r
JOIN (SELECT `Reg.No`, SubjectCode, MAX(marks) AS marks
   FROM results
   GROUP BY 1, 2) m
   ON m.`Reg.No` = r.`Reg.No`
   AND m.SubjectCode = r.SubjectCode
   AND m.marks = r.marks
GROUP BY 1, 2, 4, 5
```

The outer grouping is to break ties when a student achieves the same mark for a subject multiple times.

Comment: might add this FROM results r

Comment: That is still missing the grade column for the highest mark.

Comment: if this works then accept the answer to Give man some credit.

Comment: This query might work as expected, but with the join, it's much more complicated. It's internally using three queries, with two temporary tables and filesort and using the join buffer.I also don't like the numerical values for the group, as you can simple mess up the query, when you change the order of the columns or add some new ones.

Answer (score 0):

try like this by

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE marks > 40 Order By Marks Desc
```

this will list the result greater than 40 and highest marks will be shown first you can use limit too so you can fetch records according to your need

Comment: This will give only marks>40. But if anyone still try one attempt ans if it is less than 40, then I want to show highest marks currently achieved.This query gives only results above 40.

Comment: after DESC use limit 1. it will return only one record with highest marks